# How to configure AppHostBase virtual methods?

Tags: servicestack, host

AppHostBase has two overridable methods where you can configure your inherited Application host

- `Init()`
- `Configure(Container container)`

Is there a rule to know which is better?

For instance:

- `Container.RegisterAs<SmtpEmailer, IEmailer>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);`
- `OrmLiteConfig.CommandTimeout = 120;`
- `Container.RegisterValidators(typeof(CustomerService).Assembly);`
- `Plugins.Add(new SeqRequestLogsFeature(new SeqRequestLogsSettings(AppSettings.GetString("SeqUrl"))));`

Is it better to call these lines on `Init()` or `Configure()` or it depends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All ServiceStack Configuration should be maintained in `AppHost.Configure()` which is also the only abstract method which every AppHost needs to override.

Comment: Ok. So for what is Init() useful ?

Comment: @labilbe It's what intializes the entire AppHost which among other things calls `Configure()`.

Comment: ok. But I mean, is there a concrete scenario where overriding Init() is preferable to use more than Configure()?

Comment: @labilbe You shouldn't override it unless you absolutely need to. As an overridable method it lets you execute custom logic before and after your AppHost initializes.